# Select max DateTime column value over a year

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

Using SQL Server 2005, I have a table that records the `datetime` that a user clocks out of their shift. It stores these values in a `datetime` column.

Sometimes people have mistakenly clocked out of their shift early and then they clock out again at the right time.

I have been tasked with pulling all of the dates that a user left early for the day. There are some days that have two entries and I have to get the maximum entry for that day. They may have clocked out at the right time for the second time, but their first time is still in there.

So, there is a table that is called `tblShift` that has the time that they are supposed to clock out. This is `tblShift`. The datetime value is `tblShift.ShiftEnd`.

Then there is the table `tblCLock` that shows their types of clockouts. These could be breaks or actually clocking out at the end of their shift, or a mistaken clock out.

This is the WRONG way I am doing it:

```
SELECT 
    clockDateTime, 
    datediff(n, tblShift.ShiftEnd, tblClock.ClockDateTime) as minutes 
from 
    tblClock
INNER JOIN 
    tblShift ON tblClock.userid = tblShift.userid 
                AND Year(tblClock.ClockDateTime) = Year(tblShift.ShiftEnd) 
                AND Month(tblClock.ClockDateTime) = Month(tblShift.ShiftEnd)
                AND Day(tblClock.ClockDateTime) = Day(tblShift.ShiftEnd)
WHERE 
    tblClock.USERID = 29689 --one of the id's in the table
    and clocktypeid = 1
    and clockstatusid = 2
    and tblShift.ShiftEnd between '2011-11-11 12:00:00 AM' and '2012-11-11 11:59:59 PM'
    and tblShift.ShiftTypeID = 1
    and datediff(n, tblShift.ShiftEnd, tblClock.ClockDateTime) < 0
ORDER BY 
    tblClock.clockdatetime desc
```

What happens there is that the mistaken early clock out is used on the days that they clocked out by mistake and then clocked out at the proper time at the end of their shift.

I am trying to figure out how to work MAX into this query so that I am only getting the maximum from each day.

I have started over a few times and am not succeeding.

**tblClock**:

```
[clockID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[clockStatusID] [int] NULL,
[clockTypeID] [int] NULL,
[userID] [int] NULL,
[clockDateTime] [datetime] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_tblClock_clockDateTime]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
[clockNotes] [text] NULL,
```

**tblShift**:

```
[shiftID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[shiftTypeID] [int] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_tblShift_shiftTypeID]  DEFAULT ((1)),
[userID] [int] NULL,
[shiftStart] [datetime] NULL,
[shiftEnd] [datetime] NULL,
[shiftNotes] [text] NULL,
```

UPDATE: I have been working on this most of a day, and have gotten it to this point:

```
SELECT
max(tblClock.clockdatetime) as clockdatetime, 
max(tblShift.ShiftEnd),
datediff(n, max(tblShift.ShiftEnd), max(tblClock.ClockDateTime)) as minutes 
FROM 
tblclock
INNER JOIN 
tblShift ON tblClock.userid = tblShift.userid 
AND Year(tblClock.ClockDateTime) = Year(tblShift.ShiftEnd) 
AND Month(tblClock.ClockDateTime) = Month(tblShift.ShiftEnd)
AND Day(tblClock.ClockDateTime) = Day(tblShift.ShiftEnd)
WHERE 
tblClock.userid = 29689
AND 
tblClock.clocktypeid = 1
AND 
tblClock.clockstatusid = 2
AND 
tblShift.ShiftEnd between '2011-10-01 12:00:00 AM' AND '2012-10-01 11:59:59 PM'
AND 
tblShift.ShiftTypeID = 1
GROUP BY 
Year(tblClock.clockdatetime),Month(tblClock.clockdatetime),day(tblClock.clockdatetime)
ORDER BY 
max(tblClock.clockdatetime) desc
```

I am using my scripting language to only display those with minutes less than zero, because I can't get the AND Minutes < 0 into the where portion.

Also, thank you for the edit to properly word the question.  Marching on...

Comment: What are the possible values for clocktypeid and clockstatusid? You have to use these values to obtain the valid clock-ins, then use this resultset to determine the correct clock-outs.

Comment: ClockTypeId = 1(shift),2(lunch),3(break).  ClockStatusID = 1(clockin),2(clockout).  The clocktypeid of the early clockouts is 1 for shift and 2 for clockout.  These numbers are stored even if the clockout is done early.